# How can I put two divs alongside each other keeping the second one centered using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='centered'></div>
</div>
```

I want to center the second inner div and place the first inner div to the left of the centered one. I don't want the left div to stick to the left side of the screen (as `float:left` would did) but the opposite: the left div should "stick" to the left side of the centered div.

I would prefer to use flex for layout, but I'm open for other solutions (without JavaScript, css-only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children of flex container will follow his parent alignment rules. As you said, you need the left element to be sticked on the left of the centered one. So le left element should not be related to the container, but instead, to the centered element.

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Left {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.Centered {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
}













/* Demo only */

.Centered, .Left {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container"> 
  <div class="Centered">
    <div class="Left">Left</div>
    Centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want also the left div to be sticky (but not for the centered one), how can I achieve that? In your solution `position` field has already been used, I can't use `position: sticky` without breaking your solution.