# Two divs alongside each other: first sticked and the second centered

Tags: html, css

I want to place two divs alongside each other. Second one to be centered and the first one to be on the left from second and to be sticked / fixed. Because of the last condition [the existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202969/how-can-i-put-two-divs-alongside-each-other-keeping-the-second-one-centered-usin) does not work (attribute `position` is already used there for both divs). How can I solve this?

Comment: the last condition isn't clear, can you elaborate more? and also bring the non working code here

Comment: Why did you accept the answer in your other question then? Don't open a new one with a same problem. Edit your previous question so it's no duplicate anymore and then reopen it.

Comment: @MarkBaijens, because at that moment I didn't need the sticked condition, so this is new problem, new question

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I want to scroll the centered div normally but the first one to be fixed, always keeping it alongside the centered div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height:100%;
}

.left {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.centered {
  margin-right:auto;
  padding:5px;
  background:green;
  height:100%;
}

.left span {
  position:fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding:5px;
  background:red;
}

body {
 height:200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'><span> some content</span></div>
  <div class='centered'>centered</div>
</div>
```